# Which video editor can I use to make clips to upload?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

I am looking for an easy video editor for Ubuntu 12.04. My needs are simple: make clips and upload them on sites (cut segments from a video file with frame to frame precision, convert into common formats, resize the file).

Can anyone suggest one?

Answer (score 9):

I like OpenShot, but you can find a full list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software). Take a look to Linux section, eventually you can search in Software Manager for the given keyword.

Answer (score 5):

I had a great experience with `Kdenlive` which is also in the default Ubuntu repository. It has a bit more functions than the *OpenShot* and seemed to me more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try out Shotcut (http://shotcut.org/bin/view/Shotcut). It a cross-platform video editor translated in many languages whose developpment is led by Dan Dennedy former developper for Kdenlive. It's really simple to use with a drag n drop concept, filters (text, video, audio) and you get great results very quickly. one thing that stands out is, that there's no need to "import" clips into a project just like you do with Kdenlive and Openshot. The lastest version came out a couple of days ago (attention: new versions are 64bit only).